# Foreigner friend or foreign friend?

Tags: word-usage

> 1. I want to have a foreigner friend.
> 2. I want to have a foreign friend.

Is it correct to say foreigner friend?

Comment: I'll mention it could be *slightly* impolite or abrasive to refer to someone as a "foreigner".  It's not a very common noun to use in English, and there's a tendency for people who *do* use it to be doing so in sentences like *"I can't believe they're letting all these foreigners come in and take our jobs"*.  You might prefer to say *"I'd like to make friends with someone from another country."* or something like that.

Comment: @HostileFork Sigh. The list of words that people find offensive continues to grow, I guess. Pretty soon the only word we'll be allowed to use is "of".

Comment: @Jay That's on the list, too.  Why do you think they call it OF-fensive?

Answer (score 4):

Foreigner is a noun, foreign is an adjective.  While either example would be understood, "foreign friend" is correct.

If you wanted to use "foreigner", you could say

> My friend, who is a foreigner

Though this will convey that not only are they from another place, but that they haven't assimilated to local culture.  "Foreign friend" implies that they are from somewhere else, regardless of their cultural inclinations.

Comment: Are you sure that *foreigner friend* is really incorrect?  I hear this kind of construction a lot.  "My banker friend says interest rates are going up."  I bet it has a name.  It's almost a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), but I think not quite.

Comment: It could be, as with many constructs in English its defined by its usage.  It could be that @HostileFork pointed out, "foreigner" is often used pejoratively (at least in AmE).  Now that you mention it, I wouldn't say "foreigner friend" is _incorrect_ but I would choose almost any other way of saying it.  This is deeply connotative though, perhaps in other English-speaking countries there's less weight to the word.

Comment: Asked on English.SE: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262197/is-banker-friend-a-noun-adjunct-or-something-else

Comment: @NateEldredge - Good point about noun adjuncts, but I think it's worth noting that *foreigner* has an adjective form in *foreign*; *banker* doesn't really have an associated adjective, so we don't really have a choice anyway.